# Compare date time in SQL Timestamp with XMLGregorianCalendar and ignoring seconds in JAVA

Tags: java

I tried converting SQL Timestamp to XMLGregorianCalendar and then compare with other XMLGregorianCalendar, but the problem is if I put DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED for seconds and milliseconds while converting am getting "Invalid set of fields set for XMLGregorianCalendar"

Any suggestion please
Thanks in advance

Comment: some code would help....

Answer (score 0):

Without having more information you could do the check in a couple ways.

1) Convert the two dates to Calendar instances and Zero out the time then simply run `compareto`

2) Get the Calendar instances and manually check Year to Year , Day to Day and finally Month to Month

```
public class DateCheck
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTime(new Date());
    try
    {
      XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
      Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

      System.out.println("Are dates equal using manual check : " + manualDateCheck(timeStamp, xmlGregorianCalendar));

      Calendar timeStampCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      timeStampCalendar.setTime(timeStamp);
      System.out.println("Are dates equal using calendar check : " + calendarCheck(timeStampCalendar, xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar()));

    }
    catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  public static boolean manualDateCheck(Timestamp timestamp, XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar)
  {
    Calendar cal = xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar();
    Calendar otherCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    otherCal.setTime(timestamp);
    if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) != otherCal.get(Calendar.YEAR))
    {
      return false;
    }
    if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) != otherCal.get(Calendar.MONTH))
    {
      return false;
    }
    if (cal.get(Calendar.DATE) != otherCal.get(Calendar.DATE))
    {
      return false;
    }
    if (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) != otherCal.get(Calendar.HOUR))
    {
      return false;
    }
    if (cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) != otherCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
    {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static boolean calendarCheck(Calendar calendar1, Calendar calendar2)
  {
    return zeroCalendar(calendar1).compareTo(zeroCalendar(calendar2)) == 0;
  }

  public static Calendar zeroCalendar(Calendar calendar)
  {
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return calendar;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kenneth, calenderCheck is simpler and I will use that.. :) but I after trying many way I did in other way as below.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Kenneth, 
calenderCheck is simpler and I will use that.. :) but I after trying many way I did in other way as below.

please correct me if the below one is not,

```
public class TestMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException{

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTime(new Date());
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
    Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String sqlTimestamp = dateFormat.format(timeStamp);

    Timestamp xmlToSqlTimestamp = new Timestamp(xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
    String xmlTimestamp = dateFormat.format(xmlToSqlTimestamp);
    System.out.println(timeStamp+" : "+xmlGregorianCalendar);
    System.out.println(sqlTimestamp+" : "+xmlTimestamp);

    System.out.println("Time stamps are equal : "+sqlTimestamp.equalsIgnoreCase(xmlTimestamp));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is recreating the check needlessly and will be a lot slower.

Comment: I don't understand, It will be help full if explained where it is recreating the check needlessly, it is taking average 140 millisec.